# Marionette appRouter not working with cordova, but regular routing works?

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js, marionette

I have been using marionette appRouter for a while in my web based apps, now that I am using the same boilerplate I created for a cordova app marionette appRouter will not fire events on the controller.

```
App.core.vent.bind('app:start', function(options){
    App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Starting');
    if (Backbone.history) {
        App.controller = new Controller();
        App.router = new Router({ controller: App.controller });
        App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Backbone.history starting');
        Backbone.history.start();
    } 

    App.core.vent.trigger('app:log', 'App: Done starting and running!');
});
```

You see I pass the controller into the router then call `Backbone.history.start();` this has worked well in my web based apps.

```
module.exports = Controller = Marionette.Controller.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {

        alert('Controller initialize called');
        //this.renderView(view);

    },

    mainApp: function() {

        alert('hit main app');

    }

});
```

On the router

```
module.exports = Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
        ''            : 'mainApp'
    }
});
```

Usually this triggers `mainApp` on the controller, but when using cordova nothing happens.

However when I use the basic router then it triggers

```
module.exports = Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    routes: {
        ''            : 'mainApp'
    },
    mainApp: function() {

        alert('main app hit');

    }
});
```

Any idea why this is, does marionette react differently since the app filepath is different than a standard url or something?

Comment: have you tried to wait for the deviceready event before your initialisation?

Comment: Oh yeah, I dont initialize my app until then.